# Three tables -- Use cascade relationships or add extras?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema, stripe-payments

I am a PHP developer and have basic knowledge of MySQL yet I am working on a personal project so have to dig into it.

Billing details will be stored mimicking stripe objects. However, I am wondering if I should use indexes in cascade or use them on each table.

Let me explain through (a simplified) example. A user has a subscription. Each subscription raises an invoice a month. Each invoice raises one charge (or several if some failed.)

```
table_user
- user_id
- username
- password

table_subscription
- sub_id
- start_date
- end_date
- amount
- user_id

table_invoice
- invoice_id
- period_start
- period_end
- amount
- paid
- subscription_id

table_charge
- charge_id
- amount
- status
- failure_code
- failure_reason
- invoice_id
```

My point is that I want to quickly list each user's charges and invoices. One charge/invoice belongs to one user. Should I use uder_id key on just subscription (as charges and invoices are linked) or, should I still add user_id to both invoice and charge tables?

It's easier to SELECT but also if in the future I make charges not related to an invoice (buying a one-off extra) but linked to that user.

Looking forward to receiving some suggestions.

Comment: This is a design decision, which we cannot really answer, since we do not know all the details, nor your plans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is to use 'user_id' as a key for each table. If you have MySQL Workbench you can also link them via keys. If 'user_id' is a unique identifier for a user than it needs to be on every table where it is used. This way you do not have a table that is 'lost' and needs code or triggers to find the user. It is only one extra column per table and worth the effort. PHP will use it as an absolute point of reference back to the user, and so can your background routines.
 I would also archive the users id and IP address for a few years, just in case there is a payment issue and they close their account.